# How to indicate destination for downloaded file

Tags: java, jsf, download

I use JSF 2.0 and tomcat 7.0. To download file I use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File("file.xls"));`

How to indicate default destination, because now files are saved in workspace directory? I want to download my file to download directory wchich is default for all user. For example in Windows system all downloaded files are saved in "download".Thanks :)

Comment: +1 Good question. Why so complicated ? cant you ask user to specify download location.

Comment: Solution is 1. Search how to find default browser in java 2. Check how to get download folder location for that browser. here is a link http://unlockforus.blogspot.in/2008/07/how-to-find-or-specify-download.html

Comment: By the way your code looks, you should define the file location when creating the new `File` object: `new File(pathToDownload + "file.xls")`. Try this with a basic path (like "C:\\downloads\\" in Windows or "/home/myUser/downloads" un Unix/Linux).

Comment: @vels4j: that line of code doesn't send the file from server to client. Instead, the server is itself the client.

Comment: @BalusC I was thinking that he wants to copy file from somewhere else to the machine where he is running tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the desired target folder in the `File` constructor.

```
File downloads = new File("/path/to/download/folder");
// ...
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File(downloads, "file.xls"));
```

Please note that this question has absolutely nothing to do with JSF or Tomcat. You'd have exactly the same problem when doing so in a plain vanilla Java application.

Please also note that I assume that you are very well aware that this line of code absolutely doesn't send the file from the webserver to an arbitrary webbrowser. Instead, it saves the file in webserver's very own disk file system. You would only experience the "effect" of the file being saved in "client side" by misinterpretation when the webbrowser happens to run at physically the same machine as the webbrowser (and didn't realize that this actually doesn't happen in real world).

Comment: thanks, I rather thought about smth that wrote veks4j. Actually I change my download operation for download offered by primefaces.